# How do I pass user-input filenames to ImageMagick safely?

Tags: python, bash, imagemagick

I am generating an ImageMagick bash command using Python. Something like

```py
import subprocess

input_file = "hello.png"
output_file = "world.jpg"

subprocess.run(["convert", input_file, output_file])
```

where there might be more arguments before `input_file` or `output_file`. My question is, if either of the filenames is user provided and the user provides a filename that can be parsed as a command line option for ImageMagick, isn't that unsafe?

Answer (score 2):

If the filename starts with a dash, ImageMagick indeed could think that this is an option instead of a filename. Most programs - including AFIK the ImageMagick command line tools - follow the convention that a double-dash (`--`) denotes the end of the options. If you do a

```py
subprocess.run(["convert", "--", input_file, output_file])
```

you should be safe in this respect.

Comment: Doesn't protect you against IM options. `convert -- Foo.jpg -scale` is going to complain about missing `-scale` options. Nothing dangerous in that case, but there can be corner cases.

Comment: @xenoid : No - garbage in / garbage out. If the user passes the commands in this way, he obviously considers `-scale` as a file name, and if you know that you **need** a `-scale` option, you have to pass it explicitly before the `--`.

Answer (score 2):

From the `man` page (and a few tests), `convert` requires an input file and an output file. If you only allow two tokens and if a file name is interpreted as an option then `convert` is going to miss at least one of the files, so you'll get an ugly message but you should be fine.

Otherwise you can prefix any file name that starts with `-` with `./` (except `-` itself, which is stdin or stdout depending on position), so that it becomes an unambiguous file path to the same file.

Comment: Ideally I don't want to surprise users by telling them I can't handle their filename. I think another thing to do is pass only absolute file paths.

Comment: Yes, calling `os.path.abspath(path)` on every file is also a solution. But a single `-` denotes stdin or stdout so you cannot blindly convert to an absolute path.

Comment: in my case the file paths are provided by users in the form of files they upload to my website, users aren't specifying command line arguments.